# Is it worth piling on flags when it's known that the offending post has already been added to review queue?

Tags: discussion, flags

The recent change in the flagging system redirects all NAA and LQ flaqs to Low Quality Review queue.

In the past, it was still worth piling on flags, so that the community moderators could act on them faster (or maybe the post would be deleted after a number of flags?). Anyway, that was the past.

In the current system, is there any worth in flagging a post which we know that it is currently in the review queue (evident by the canned comments)?

Comment: It was never the case that NAA or VLQ flags resulted in deletion, regardless of how many there were.  And piling on flags wouldn't help mods actually address flags any quicker, it just meant that that post would be cutting in line, taking attention away from other flags.  Flags beyond the first were almost never helpful in the past (nor are they any different now).

Comment: @Servy: I heard that piling on 3-4 flags push them up in the list of flags, so the mods can judge them quicker, since getting that many flags means that there are as many people agreeing that the post should be gone. Anyway, I think it doesn't really solve anything to discuss the old system here.

Comment: The mod isn't going to *not* look at or evaluate the post just because it has 3 flags.  They're still going to be looking at it, just like when it has 1 flag.

Comment: Some kinds of flags carry with them an "extra -1 vote", which can be useful to non-mods?

Comment: @Roombatron5000: I have voted to close this question as the first question you cite.

Comment: Hitting the flags is like cheering at a sporting match, not necessarily more effectual, but at least has the perception of participation.

Comment: @Nodak: I think piling a few flags should help preventing robo-reviewers or people who don't know how reviewing works from giving a chance for the post to stay.